# Restricted partitions without 1s and 2s

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions

I am interested in partitions of an integer n which do not have 1 and 2 as its part. That is, I am looking to write 
$$n=3^{n_3}4^{n_4}\cdots.$$

Now, I want to count this. And any other information about generating function or recursive formula will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy with generating functions. Let $a(n)$ be such a count. Then,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)q^n=\prod_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac1{1-x^k}.$$
For more information, you may like to [explore this](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+9%2C+10%2C+13%2C+17%2C+21%2C+25&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: From the formula in the question, OP seems to be interested in multiplicative partitions, not additive ones.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I think it is rather a matter of notation.

Comment: @Wolfgang In which sense? The two concepts seem completely different to me. For instance, ignoring the constraint on $3$ in the question, the sequence of "multiplicative partitions" is such that $m_p=1$ for each prime $p$, while the sequence of "additive partitions" $a_n$ is increasing.

Comment: Or instead, keeping into account that constraint, the sequence OP asks for is such that $a_{2d}=0$ for each odd $d$, while the sequence suggested by this answer is an increasing one.

Comment: Well I don't think the OP thought of all this. In combinatorial words, repetitions are usually written as exponents. It seems to me that for repeated parts of an (additive) partition, it is more common to use indices. But $n=3^{n_3}4^{n_4}\cdots$ is easier to read than multiple indices $n=3_{n_3}4_{n_4}\cdots$. :)

Comment: @Wolfgang I guess you are right, since the OP accepted this answer. But I realize that in the end it's just a game of "guess what the real question was". :)